# Why would Chrome and Firefox handle Javascript links differently?

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I have a web site that works perfectly in FireFox 9.0.1.

In Chrome 16, it fails catastrophically. Too many errors to go through them all.

However, to pick one problem to start with (and hope that it be a clue that will help illuminate the core issues), I have buttons that are driven by Javascript to simply take someone to a new page.

The code for these buttons is as simple as it gets:

```
var siteURL = "http://mywebsite.com/";
function goHome()
{
    window.location = siteURL + "index.html";
}
```

In FireFox, if I click the button that executes this code, I get taken to index.html. Easy peasy.

In Chrome, if I click this button, I get a 404 error page that says:

> The requested URL /undefinedindex.html was not found on this server.

Why are these browsers behaving differently?

How do I get Chrome to play along?

---

As requested in the comments, I put `alert(siteURL);` in the function.

Firefox outputs:

> http://mywebsite.com/

Chrome outputs

> undefined

Comment: Where does the global `siteURL` come from? You should just debug out why `siteURL` is undefined in chrome.

Comment: Put '`alert(siteURL);`' in that function immediately before the assignment to `window.location` and tell us what it prints.

Comment: Also, why are you using Javascript to do something `<a>` will do for you for free?

Comment: I think you'll find Chrome does the concatenation first to get `"undefinedindex.html"` but then assumes a leading `"/"` since that string doesn't contain a path. (You can test this by saying `window.location="index.html";`.) So don't worry about the slash, worry about why `siteURL` is undefined.

Comment: @xdazz: Yes I can and will, but how is it possible that Firefox thinks it is defined and Chrome doesn't? The variable is either defined or not, isn't it? This isn't two sets of code for either browser, it's the exact same code, so why would browsers think of the same variable differently?

Comment: @Zack: It's a long story. The short story is "There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio, Than are dreamt of in your philosophy." ;)

Comment: @DaveMG Because they are different browser, they may think differently if there is unstandard code.

Comment: @xdazz: Okay. If there is nonstandard code there, then I'd be happy to change it. It seems pretty basic to me, though. So basic that I'm surprised it would be intrpreted differently.

Comment: Your code works fine for me in both FF and Chrome on the mac. I fired off your function with <a onclick="goHome()" href="#">hello</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Chrome 16:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.siteURL = "http://mywebsite.com/";
function goHome() {
    console.log('moo?');
    window.location.href = window.siteURL + "index.html";
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <a href="#" onclick="goHome(); return false;">go home</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this has caused the entire site to break, both in FireFox, Chrome, and in my IDE (NetBeans).

Comment: tbh knowing that the exact same script works for someone else IS helpful. tells you that ur setup is fscked.

Comment: Without specifics about why, it might mean that *your* set up is the exceptional one.

Comment: I now see the error of my ways. I misread your code, and I was writing `var window.siteURL = 'mysite.com'`, but (for reasons I'm fuzzy on), if one switches to using `window`, then one doesn't need to to put the `var` declaration in front. Oh... wait... because `window` is already declared. I get it now. I still don't know why Chrome likes this better, but it works, and I've learned to just accept the mysterious will of the browsers. Thanks for the code!

Answer (score 1):

you should not use `window.location.` and instead assign the url to `window.location.href`

Therefore, it should have been

```
function goHome()
{
    window.location.href = siteURL + "index.html";
}
```

And also...you get that 'undefined' value because you probably didn't assign any value to siteURL, or you forgot to declare it. make sure it really points to your current root url (if you want it to be)

Comment: Sorry, but it seems clear that I did assign siteURL because FireFox could find it. I can believe that maybe there is some kind of difference in how the code is interpreted, but if it were simply undeclared, it would *never* work for either browser. However, +1 for the tip on using .href.

Answer (score 0):

If all browsers behaved exactly identical, I would be out of work.

It's impossible to tell what exactly goes wrong without seeing the complete code.

Judging from the snippet abobe, there must be some other function (in the same scope as `goHome`) that assigns `undefined` to `siteURL` and gets called prior to `goHome`